# Merge Sort Problems - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, merge

What's wrong with my code? It prints only a part of the vect values. Seems that the while loop breaks at some point. I don't understand why.

```
def print_list(vect):
    for i in range(0, len(vect)):
        print(vect[i])

def merge_sort(vect):
    left = []
    right = []    
    result = []

    for i in range(0, int(len(vect)/2)):
        left.append(vect[i])
    for i in range(int(len(vect)/2), len(vect)):
        right.append(vect[i])

    left.sort()
    right.sort()
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    print(len(result))
    return result

vect = [3, 1, 5, 7, 10, 2, 0]

vect = merge_sort(vect)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're calling `left.sort()` and `right.sort()`. That uses Python's internal sorting functions on each half of the list, which makes your implementation of mergesort totally pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your mistake is that after your while loop

```
while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
  ...
```

it may be (and most probably would) that either `i < len(left)` or `j < len(right)`, so you need to append appropriate part's suffix to the answer. It's easy to do with

```
result += left[i:]
result += right[j:]
```

**Explanation:**

Imagine the merge procedure: you have i and j at 0 at start, and at every step you move one of them forward. When you stop ? When one of them reaches the end. Let's say i has reached the end. Hereby you added the whole left part to the result, but there are still some elements in right between j and len(right), so you have to add them to the answer too.

**Offtop**:

You are implementing merge sort, so please have

```
left = merge_sort( left )
right = merge_sort( right )
```

instead of

```
left.sort()
right.sort()
```

**Attention:** you have to add the following check to your code at the beginning of merge function to avoid infinite recursion:

```
if len( vect ) == 1:
   return vect
```

Also in your print_list function you can just use

```
print vect
```

or at least

```
for x in vect
print x
```

Comment: @user1392136: yes, so it will break when i >= len(left) OR j >= len(right). The other index may still remain less.

Comment: so the answer is that I need OR instead of AND there.. if I try with OR, I receive index out of range...

Comment: @user1392136: no, the answer is that you need AND, and you need to add the unviewed part of left or right after the while

Comment: ah.. I understand.. Thank you. One more thing, if I call left = merge_sort(left) I've receive maximum recursion deep exceeded.

Comment: @user1392136: I've edded explanation to this and your previous comment to the answer. Just check if the size of array is 1 to stop the recursion at that point.

Answer (score 3):

The while loop exits as soon as either left or right is exhausted.  This leaves all the elements left in the unexhausted list unmerged.

Change your code to this:

```
def print_list(vect):
    for i in range(0, len(vect)):
        print(vect[i])

def merge_sort(vect):
    left = []
    right = []

    result = []
    for i in range(0, int(len(vect)/2)):
        left.append(vect[i])
    for i in range(int(len(vect)/2), len(vect)):
        right.append(vect[i])

    left.sort();
    right.sort();
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    if i < len(left):
        result.extend(left[i:])
    else:
        result.extend(right[j:])

    print(len(result))
    return result

vect = [3, 1, 5, 7, 10, 2, 0]

vect = merge_sort(vect)
print vect
```

If you're using the sort method on left and right, I'm a little confused as to why you're not just using it on the list as a whole.  But I suppose you have your reasons. :)

Edit: I put the entire block of code there so you can see it.  When I run this, it prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10], which is correct.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to add this at the end of while. However it doesn't works...

Comment: I adjusted the answer to be a little more explicit.  Maybe it works for you now.

Comment: I don't understand why and what I need to extend to make it works... Can you give me some details in words what you do with your new lines of code?

Comment: The extend method takes a list as a parameter.  It iterates over the list and appends each element to the parent list-like object.  What I've done above is to take the remaining parts of each list (that's done using list slice notation [i:] or [j:]) and just add all those remaining elements to the result list.

Comment: Can this be considered a true merge sort when it's not recursive?

Your calls to left.sort() and right.sort() technically should call back to MergeSort, am I wrong?